# How To Group and Sort Array element base Specific Character

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array Like This :

```
array("10", "1001","12", "1201","1002", "1202","120101", "120201","13");
```

i need Loop in Php  to  sort and group with Two Character of value to output Like This :

```
-10
        --1001
        --1002

-12

        --1201
                    --- 120101
        --1202
                   --- 120201
-13
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We expect you to do a little more here, than to just “drop off” your requirement.

Comment: Sorry For That I edit Ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `usort` by string compare and the add prefix to each element with `str_repeat`

Consider:

```
$arr = array("10", "1001","12", "1201","1002", "1202","120101", "120201","13");

usort($arr, "strcasecmp"); // sorting the array by string and not array
function addPre($v) {
    $mul = strlen($v) / 2; // check the string size and divided by 2 as your example
    return str_repeat("\t", $mul - 1) . str_repeat("-", $mul) . $v;
}

foreach($arr as $e)
    echo addPre($e) . PHP_EOL;
```

Reference: [str-repeat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php), [usort](https://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)